# VueJS Dynamic icon class

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have the following `i` element:

```
<i class="icon-user custom-style test"
          v-if="employee.status === 0 && this.employeeType === 'admin'">
    </i>
```

I want to replace class icon-user depending on the `v-if` same condition.

So, if `employee.status === 0 && this.employeeType === 'admin'` the icon class should be `icon-user`, otherwise it should be `icon-home`

Any clue?

Comment: What you're asking for doesn't make sense. If the condition is _falsy_, your entire element won't show so what's the point in setting a different class on it?

Comment: Also, you don't need the `this` prefix in your templates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
computed: {
  classObject: function() {
    if(this.employee.status === 0 && this.employeeType === 'admin')
    {
      return "icon-user";
    }
    else return "icon-home"
```

```html
<i v-bind:class="classObject"></i>
```

This should be a solution,[a lot of other options in the docs.](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html)

Comment: Your `else` is kinda redundant. You can just have `return 'icon-home'` at that stage

Comment: Or even just `return this.employee.status === 0 && this.employeeType === 'admin' ? 'icon-user' : 'icon-home'`. Anyway, +1 good answer